# Secret getting loaded from secret-manager but not getting read

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-secrets-manager

I am using below dependency for fetching secrets config

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config</artifactId>
<version>${version.spring.cloud.starter.aws-secret-manager-config}</version>
</dependency>
```

```
aws:
  secretsmanager:
    prefix: /secret
    default-context: application
    profile-separator: _
    fail-fast: false
    name: application
    enabled: true
    region: eu-central-1
```

Application is able to load secret as below in logs

```
[INFO] Loading secrets from AWS Secret Manager secret with name: /secret/application_dev, optional: true
```

but not able to read them in application. And acc to the class `AwsSecretsManagerPropertySource` present in the above dependency i should also get the below log as well.

```java
LOG.debug("Populating property retrieved from AWS Secrets Manager: " + secretEntry.getKey());
```

but i am not getting this log and application is not able to read the configs fetched from secret manager.

Can anyone help in this?

Comment: Add more code, give a little bit wider scope

Comment: I am fetching redis secrets(host,port,username,password and many other related ) from AWS-Secret-Manager. During the execution phase of appilcation, Application fails as it is not able to find the configs property. these configs have loaded by aws but are not able to read them in the application. you can checkout sources of the spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config package.